# Is there any easy way to make a Bootstrap radio button group from an enum in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, enums

I've an enum about priorities:

```
public enum Priorities
    {
        P1,
        P2,
        P3,
        P4,
        P5,
    }
```

I'd like to make a radio button group in Bootstrap, to choose which priority should be given as the value of the following model property:

```
public Priorities Priority { get; set; }
```

I've found this Bootstrap template:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">Radio 3</label>
</div>
```

but unfortunately I don't know how to make it work, that after selecting the right button, the value will be given to the new object created in the database.

Comment: I recommend you create a tag helper which is get an enum or other type of list to make radio buttons. Also, you can use the name enum as a value or use numbers instead of enum name.

Answer (score 0):

First add values to your enum:

```
public enum Priorities : int
{
    P1 = 1,
    P2 = 2,
    P3 = 3,
    P4 = 4,
    P5 = 5,
}
```

Then loop through each value of your enumeration and add value to IDs.

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
@foreach(int e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Priorities)))
{
    var buttonId = $"btnradio{e}";
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="@buttonId" autocomplete="off" checked="@(e==1)">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for=""@buttonId"">Radio @e</label>
}
</div>
```

#### Output:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked="checked">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">Radio 3</label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio4" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio4">Radio 4</label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio5" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio5">Radio 5</label>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not sending the value into the model property so it does not matter what I choose the property will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works:

```html
@foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Priorities)))
{
        <input type="radio" asp-for="" class="btn-check" id="@value" value="@((int)value)">
        <label asp-for="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="@value">@value</label>
}
```